# Trouble with Multi-Hop SSH with password prompt C#

Tags: c#, ssh-tunnel, ssh.net

How can I pass a password to an SSH prompt that will not let me send via the command?

**This is not working**

```
 KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod DEVICEkauth = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(DEVICEsshUname);
            PasswordAuthenticationMethod DEVICEpauth = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(DEVICEsshUname, DEVICEsshPass);
```

I am trying to do a multi-hop ssh connection and it fails on the third hop due to SSH Protocol identification.

> [Multi hop SSH through SSH.NET in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759639/) does not solve my
>   problem, it did help me get most of the way. This problem is trying to
>   do a third hop which does not work.

This is via a VeloCloud Gateway connecting to a Velo Edge then connecting to an end device (DiGi Transport)

**What I have so far:**

```
    int sssshTimeOut = 1000;

    KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod VCGkauth = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(VCGsshUname);
    PasswordAuthenticationMethod VCGpauth = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(VCGsshUname, VCGsshPass);

    VCGkauth.AuthenticationPrompt += new EventHandler<AuthenticationPromptEventArgs>(VCGHandleKeyEvent);

    SshClient sshVCG = new SshClient(new ConnectionInfo(VCGsshHost, VCGsshPort, VCGsshUname, VCGpauth, VCGkauth));
    if (sssshTimeOut != 0)
    {
        sshVCG.ConnectionInfo.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sssshTimeOut);
    }

    void VCGHandleKeyEvent(Object sender, AuthenticationPromptEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (AuthenticationPrompt prompt in e.Prompts)
        {
            if (prompt.Request.IndexOf("Password:", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
            {
                prompt.Response = VCGsshPass;
            }
        }
    }

    KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod EDGEkauth = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(EDGEsshUname);
    PasswordAuthenticationMethod EDGEpauth = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(EDGEsshUname, EDGEsshPass);

    EDGEkauth.AuthenticationPrompt += new EventHandler<AuthenticationPromptEventArgs>(EDGEHandleKeyEvent);
    void EDGEHandleKeyEvent(Object sender, AuthenticationPromptEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (AuthenticationPrompt prompt in e.Prompts)
        {
            if (prompt.Request.IndexOf("Password:", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
            {
                prompt.Response = EDGEsshPass;
            }
        }
    }

    KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod DEVICEkauth = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(DEVICEsshUname);
    PasswordAuthenticationMethod DEVICEpauth = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(DEVICEsshUname, DEVICEsshPass);

    DEVICEkauth.AuthenticationPrompt += new EventHandler<AuthenticationPromptEventArgs>(DEVICEHandleKeyEvent);
    void DEVICEHandleKeyEvent(Object sender, AuthenticationPromptEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (AuthenticationPrompt prompt in e.Prompts)
        {
            if (prompt.Request.IndexOf("password:", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
            {
                prompt.Response = DEVICEsshPass;
            }
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Connecting to VCG: "+ VCGsshHost + "");
    sshVCG.Connect();

    Console.WriteLine("Sending ARP command to VCG: " + VCGsshHost + "");
    var commandVCG = sshVCG.CreateCommand("arp -n");
    var resultVCG = commandVCG.Execute();
    Console.WriteLine(resultVCG);

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Forwarding SSH connection to Edge: " + EDGEsshHost + "");
    var portVCG = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", uintVCGsshPort, EDGEsshHost, uintEDGEsshPort);
    sshVCG.AddForwardedPort(portVCG);
    portVCG.Start();
    if (portVCG.IsStarted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Forwarding SSH connection to Edge: Started!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Forwarding SSH connection to Edge: seems to have failed.....");
    }

    SshClient sshEDGE = new SshClient(new ConnectionInfo(portVCG.BoundHost, (int)portVCG.BoundPort, EDGEsshUname, EDGEpauth, EDGEkauth));
    sshEDGE.Connect();

    Console.WriteLine("Sending ARP command to Edge: " + EDGEsshHost + "");
    var commandEDGE = sshEDGE.CreateCommand("arp -n");
    var resultEDGE = commandEDGE.Execute();
    Console.WriteLine(resultEDGE);

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Forwarding SSH connection to EndDevice: " + DEVICEsshHost + "");
    var portEDGE = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", uintEDGEsshPort, DEVICEsshHost, uintDEVICEsshPort);
    sshEDGE.AddForwardedPort(portEDGE);
    //sshVCG.AddForwardedPort(portEDGE);
    portEDGE.Start();
    if (portEDGE.IsStarted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Forwarding SSH connection to End Device: Started!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Forwarding SSH connection to End Device: seems to have failed.....");
    }

    SshClient sshDEVICE = new SshClient(new ConnectionInfo(portEDGE.BoundHost, (int)portEDGE.BoundPort, DEVICEsshUname, DEVICEpauth, DEVICEkauth));
    //SshClient sshDEVICE = new SshClient(new ConnectionInfo(portVCG.BoundHost, (int)portVCG.BoundPort, DEVICEsshUname, DEVICEpauth, DEVICEkauth));
    //SshClient sshDEVICE = new SshClient(portEDGE.BoundHost, (int)portEDGE.BoundPort, DEVICEsshUname, DEVICEsshPass);
    sshDEVICE.Connect();

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Sending HW command to End Device: " + DEVICEsshHost + "");
    var commandDEVICE = sshDEVICE.CreateCommand("hw");
    var resultDEVICE = commandDEVICE.Execute();
    Console.WriteLine(resultDEVICE);
```

I am expecting the SSH to connect to the VGC, then the Edge, then the end device, and run a command.

This process gets just as far if I do it via Plink...

**Error:**

> Renci.SshNet.Common.SshConnectionException: 'Server response does not
>   contain SSH protocol identification.'

**Plink**

```
Plink Window 1

C:\Users\ncarter>Plink.exe -ssh -L 4000:xxx.xxx.xxx.2:22 xxxxxxx@xx.xx.xxx.85 -P 10444
Using username "xxxxxxx".
xxxxxx@xx.xx.xxx.85's password:
Welcome to Velocloud VCG (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-160-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

Last login: Fri Oct 11 18:44:59 2019 from xxx.xxx.x.42
]0;xxxxxx@xxxx-xxlab: ~xxxxxx@xxxx-xxlab:~$

Plink Window 2

C:\Users\ncarter>Plink.exe -ssh -L 8001:xxx.xxx.xx.1:xxx97 xxxx@127.0.0.1 -P 4000
Using username "xxxxx".
Using keyboard-interactive authentication.
Password:


BusyBox v1.23.2 (2018-10-19 16:11:09 UTC) built-in shell (ash)

  _    __     __      ________                __
 | |  / /__  / /___  / ____/ /___  __  ______/ /
 | | / / _ \/ / __ \/ /   / / __ \/ / / / __  /
 | |/ /  __/ / /_/ / /___/ / /_/ / /_/ / /_/ /
 |___/\___/_/\____/\____/_/\____/\__,_/\__,_/

                                  VeloCloud Inc.
------------------------------------------------
velocloud Test-Edge-1:~# [6narp
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.11.1             ether   00:04:2d:07:b9:1f   C                     ge4
xx.xxx.xxx.227           ether   50:7b:9d:35:1d:12   C                     br-network1
SIP-xxxx.xxx             ether   80:5e:c0:29:61:ad   C                     br-network1
198.19.0.33              ether   00:50:56:91:ff:2e   C                     ge3
198.19.0.1               ether   90:6c:ac:bb:c9:8c   C                     ge3
198.19.0.32              ether   00:50:56:91:7f:da   C                     ge3
xxx.xxx.xx.4             ether   50:7b:9d:35:1d:12   C                     br-network1
velocloud Test-Edge-1:~# [6nssh -p xxx97 xxxxxx@192.168.11.1 -t 'hw'
xxxxxx@192.168.11.1's password:

SN:506143
Welcome. Your access level is SUPER

ss506143>
Serial Number: 506143
HW Rev: 3205b
MAC 0: 00042d07b91f
MAC 1: 00042df7b91f
MAC 2: 00042de7b91f
MAC 3: 00042dd7b91f
MAC 4: 00042dc7b91f
MAC 5: 000000000000
MAC 6: 000000000000
Model: WR11
Part#: WR11-L800-DE1-SU
RAM: 64 MB
OK

ss506143>Connection to 192.168.11.1 closed.
velocloud Test-Edge-1:~# [6n
```

Comment: See [Multi hop SSH through SSH.NET in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48759639/850848)

Comment: I checked that out before posting my question, that solution does not properly authenticate the SSH connections. it fails on the first connection. 

Again, the SSH connections (both) require keyboard Interactive Authentication.

Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: OK, I know that you need to use keyboard authentication. But I believe that your keyboard authentication code is correct. It's the port forwarding code that looks wrong to me. So use my code for port forwarding, just replace the password authentication with keyboard interactive authentication.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, Thank you, that was it! I needed to use the portVCG.BoundHost and the portVCG.BoundPort variables, they replaced EDGEsshHost and EDGEsshPort variables. 

**What the line looks like now**
SshClient sshEDGE = new SshClient(new ConnectionInfo(portVCG.BoundHost, (int)portVCG.BoundPort, EDGEsshUname, EDGEpauth, EDGEkauth));

I feel dumb for missing this!

Comment: I think I need to add the new port to the first hop so it looks like sshVCG.AddForwardedPort(portEDGE);. I will test this as soon as I can.

Comment: Please forget the first problem, and edit your question to focus on the new problem only. The question was already way too complex before, let only now -- That includes cleaning up the comments above.

Comment: Adding the new port to the first hop did not work.

I modified the question and removed the comment.

Comment: So show us how you do that in in PuTTY for comparison.

Comment: Ok, sure thing, I will put the putty contents back up when I get in the office in the morning.

Comment: I added the Putty output.

Comment: But that's not port forwarding. We need to know if you can chain three instances of PuTTY via port forwarding.

Comment: I edited the post to reflect the Plink (nit Putty) SSH tunnels. I reframed my question to try and pass the password via C# as if I typed it (because this works in Plink). 

I think I need to abandon the third SSH tunnel hop idea :(...

Comment: I found a solution, please see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**I have found an answer that suites my specific situation:**

*I was only ever able to SSH to the VCG(First device) then SSH tunnel (forward) to the Edge(Second device), and finally just run the SSH command on the Edge to pass the command to the DiGi(Third Device), then listen for the trigger to key in the password.*

> What I did was create a PipeStream called 'input' then started a shell
>   to the Edge called 'shell' using the 'input' PipeStream as the shells
>   input. I then created a StreamWriter called 'streamWriter' on the
>   'input' PipeStream.
>
> I then sent my SSH command to the sshEDGE shell and listened for the
>   word 'password' on the PipeStream and passed in the required password.
>
> Notice on the while loop, I am resetting the position to 0 each loop.
>
> I am then listening for the word "closed" or a specified timeout to
>   know when to exit the second while loop.
>
> I then StreamRead the 'output' and assign it to my 'ssdeviceResponse'
>   var (reader.ReadToEnd();).

```
ssdeviceResponse = "";
uint uintssvcgPort = (uint)(int)ssvcgPort;
uint uintEDGEsshPort = (uint)(int)ssedgePort;
uint uintssdevicePort = (uint)(int)ssdevicePort;
int sssshTimeOut = 1000;

KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod VCGkauth = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(ssvcgUN);
PasswordAuthenticationMethod VCGpauth = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(ssvcgUN, ssvcgPass);

VCGkauth.AuthenticationPrompt += new EventHandler<AuthenticationPromptEventArgs>(VCGHandleKeyEvent);

void VCGHandleKeyEvent(Object sender, AuthenticationPromptEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (AuthenticationPrompt prompt in e.Prompts)
    {
        if (prompt.Request.IndexOf("Password:", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
        {
            prompt.Response = ssvcgPass;
        }
    }
}

KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod EDGEkauth = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(ssedgeUN);
PasswordAuthenticationMethod EDGEpauth = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(ssedgeUN, ssedgePass);

EDGEkauth.AuthenticationPrompt += new EventHandler<AuthenticationPromptEventArgs>(EDGEHandleKeyEvent);
void EDGEHandleKeyEvent(Object sender, AuthenticationPromptEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (AuthenticationPrompt prompt in e.Prompts)
    {
        if (prompt.Request.IndexOf("Password:", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
        {
            prompt.Response = ssedgePass;
        }
    }
}

SshClient sshVCG = new SshClient(new ConnectionInfo(ssvcgAddress, ssvcgPort, ssvcgUN, VCGpauth, VCGkauth));
if (sssshTimeOut != 0)
{
    sshVCG.ConnectionInfo.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(sssshTimeOut);
}
sshVCG.Connect();

var portVCG = new ForwardedPortLocal("127.0.0.1", ssedgeAddress, uintEDGEsshPort);
sshVCG.AddForwardedPort(portVCG);
portVCG.Start();

SshClient sshEDGE = new SshClient(new ConnectionInfo(portVCG.BoundHost, (int)portVCG.BoundPort, ssedgeUN, EDGEpauth, EDGEkauth));
sshEDGE.Connect();


var input = new PipeStream();
var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(input) { AutoFlush = true };
Stream outPut = new MemoryStream();
var outPutEXT = new MemoryStream();

var shell = sshEDGE.CreateShell(input, outPut, outPutEXT);
shell.Start();

streamWriter.WriteLine("ssh -p " + ssdevicePort + " " + ssdeviceUN + "@" + ssdeviceAddress + " -t '" + ssdeviceCommand + "'");


int Count = 0;
while (input.CanRead)
{
    outPut.Position = 0;
    StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(outPut);
    string i = reader1.ReadToEnd();
    if (i.Contains("password"))
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(ssdevicePass);
        break;
    }
}


while (input.CanRead)
{
    Count = Count + 1;
    Thread.Sleep(2000); //Added this because the shell would close if I read to fast, weird...
    outPut.Position = 0;
    StreamReader reader1 = new StreamReader(outPut);
    string i = reader1.ReadToEnd();
    if (i.Contains("closed"))
    {
        break;
    }
    else if (Count >= 10)
    {
        //Timeout
        break;
    }
}

outPut.Position = 0;
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(outPut);
ssdeviceResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
//Console.WriteLine(ssdeviceResponse);
//Console.WriteLine("!!!END!!!");

streamWriter.Dispose();
reader.Dispose();
outPutEXT.Dispose();
outPut.Dispose();
```