# how to use Renci.SshNet in X++(or C#) to securely send files from other servers, do you use port forward?

Tags: c#, sftp, x++, transfer, ssh-tunnel

I want to send csv file from FileServer server (FL) to Destination server (DEST) using Renci.SshNet in C# program.
The program starts on the Application server (AP).
The FL and DEST are allowed to communicate with the firewall, but the AP and DEST server are not allowed to communicate directly with the firewall.

Could you give me a simple X++ or C# sample source?

Most importantly, the communication between the FL server and DEST server is encrypted.

I added my question below.

[image]

Currently AP and DEST are allowed to connect with firewall. Since AP and FL are in the same network segment, FL's file folder can be directly referenced as a network folder.
In the future, AP and DEST will be denied connection by the firewall, and FL and DEST will be allowed to connect. And the situation where the FL file folder can be directly referenced from the AP as a network folder remains unchanged.

I would be grateful if you could give me advice on how to rewrite the program source only a little to make a secure connection in which the range of the Internet connection is encrypted.

I will show you a simplified version of the X++ program source on our system today.

```
Public static void transferFile(str fileName) { 

    Microsoft.Dynamics.IntegrationFramework.Adapter.FileSystem fileSystem;
    Renci.SshNet.SftpClient sftpClient;
    System.IO.FileStream fileStream;
    FilePath     filePath;
    FilePath     filePathProcessed;
    FTPHostName  hostNameAddress;
    FTPLoginUser loginUser;
    FTPLoginPwd  loginPwd;

    int portSFTP = 22; 
    hostNameAddress = "sftp.samplecompany.com"
    loginUser       = "SFTPUSER"
    loginPwd        = "PASSWORD"
    filePath        = "\\FL\CSVfolder\"

    fileSystem = AifUtil::getClrObject(#FileSystemProgId);
    fileSystem = new Microsoft.Dynamics.IntegrationFramework.Adapter.FileSystem();
    fullFileName = filePath + fileName;
    sftpClient = new Renci.SshNet.SftpClient(hostNameAddress, portSFTP, loginUser, loginPwd);

    ttsBegin; 

    sftpClient.Connect ();
    fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(fullFileName, System.IO.FileMode ::Open);
    sftpClient.UploadFile(fileStream, fileName);
    fileStream.Dispose();
    sftpClient.Dispose();

    ttsCommit;

}
```

Comment: To tell the truth, I want more X++ sample source than C# language. However, since C# is said to be similar to X++, C# is also appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The port forwarding is indeed one option. But it won't allow you to transfer the files from FL to DEST. You would have to download the files from FL to APP. And then upload it using the port forwarding from APP to DEST with post forwarded via FL.

---

If you want a direct transfer, all you can do is to run a command-line SFTP client via SSH shell session from APP to FL to transfer from FL to DEST.

Comment: Dear Martin

Thank you for your answer. So it will be helpful.
Do you think it possible to transfer files directly from FL to DEST using multi hop?
Could you refer to the SITE below.

Multi hop SSH tunnel
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759639/multi-hop-ssh-through-ssh-net-in-c-sharp

Comment: *"Do you think it possible to transfer files directly from FL to DEST using multi hop?"* – I do not get you. I've answered that question above already.

Comment: Dear Mr.Martin, sorry for asking the same question twice. I added to my question. I can't quite understand why I need to download because the folder from AP to FL can be referenced as a network folder.

Comment: If you can reference the file on FL using a network path, you do not have to *code* the download from FL to APP. But technically the file will be downloaded nevertheless (the file contents must be fetched from FL to APP to be uploaded to DEST, but it happens transparently in your case).